# How to reorganize iOS project to avoid memory issues

Tags: ios, memory

I am building my first project that is an interactive ebook app for the iPad

I started with the Single View App template from XCode

So far, the project is mostly a series of block animated transitions between UIImageViews and MPMovieController videos, very serial so far

Everything is coded within a single view under a single view - the image views fade in and out with alpha animations

I am beginning to run into memory issues. I've used memory instruments and see that most everything is loaded into memory at the beginning (images from the InterfaceBuilder) aside from some videos instantiated at runtime

My question is - how should I reorganize my code to better utilize memory?  Should I separate into different views under one view controller, or have multiple view controllers?

And which might be the most straight forward to implement?

Comment: multiple view controllers - make the transitions between UIViewController's so that iOS can help you unload unnecessary stuff

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  There really isn't enough in your post to know what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are very memory-intensive. So:

- Do not load an image until you actually need it (for display). When you are done with it (the image view is no longer visible), release it (by setting that image view's image to nil). Do not maintain the images in an array or anything like that. Do not create the image views preloaded with images in advance in the nib.
- When you actually need an image for display, load it in code using `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, not `imageNamed:`. Thus you prevent caching of the image.
- It is a waste of memory to work with an image larger than the display size. If these images are large, you can save a lot of memory up front if you load the image at the actual size needed for display. This is easy to do with Image IO framework and `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use multiple view controllers and separate your code in small separated views and objescts that controll you app flow..

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand it's better to have multiple views and so on..but it's a pain to rewrite code you worked on (unless it's absolutely necessary).

In my opinion if you don't have anything unnecessary in memory (i.e. when you take a view off screen you release the memory it used) you don't need to do anything.

After all, even if you split the code as it should have been, if your memory management is good, it will take the exact same memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a single view controller:

- Load your images lazily from code. Keep an array of the image *names* rather than the images themselves, and load them just before you need them.
- Make sure your images aren't larger than they need to be.
- Recycle your image views. If the user won't see more than two image views at a time (including both the from and to in a transition), you should only have two image views.
- Don't worry about whether the images are cached; iOS's caches are designed to release their contents under stress. That said, **do not** implement your own caching system. You might not release images properly under stress. If you need caching, use `NSCache`.